# Touch Bar Media Play/Pause button controls Safari, not iTunes

Tags: itunes, safari, touch-bar

I often want to pause my iTunes music when watching a video in Safari. Currently on some sites (but not all) the Pause button starts controlling the video in Safari in stead of iTunes.

How to permanently link the buttons to iTunes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BeardedSpice](http://beardedspice.github.io), solved this for me. It was intended to allow the media keys to control services in Chrome, but it also can lock the media keys to iTunes.

Comment: Thanks! After deselecting all players this appears to work!

Comment: +1 for this answer but I want one more thing, if iTunes is closed open it and play! Currently nothing happens if I press play when iTunes closed.

Comment: @KcFnMi Question is, what specifically should iTunes play if it's not open?

Answer (score -1):

The touch bar is context sensitive and changes depending on which app is running. The touch bar will control the foreground application or the one that is currently active active. If you are watching a video on Safari the toucher will control Safari, to get it to control iTunes you will need to make iTunes the active application.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to prevent this behavior. The old media keys weren't mapped to safari-videos, seems logical to expect the same behavior of the touch bar.

Comment: You could try reading through this link and see if that helps. http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-use-customise-touch-bar-on-macbook-pro-2016-3648472/

Comment: Almost reviving this from the grave, but this issue doesn't happens with Spotify. It seems to only relate to iTunes..