# Keep Safari from hijacking the media buttons from controlling iTunes

Tags: macos, keyboard, itunes, safari, preferences

I'm on a Mac with no TouchBar (so [I don't think this answer will help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280494/touch-bar-media-play-pause-button-controls-safari-not-itunes)) running 10.13. I had YouTube open and my media buttons weren't useful for stopping iTunes so that I could start a video. Is there a setting that will stop Safari from being able to use those buttons?

I would prefer not having to install 3rd party software to do this.

*This is still going on in macOS 13.13.1 (a)*

Comment: the workaround I'm currently using is http://bolzoneapps.tumblr.com/silicio-widget. It doesn't make the play/pause button work correctly, but it does give me an easy way to play/pause itunes with the mouse. (and also records my tracks to last.fm, which is a bonus for me)

Comment: So, 5 years later, and this is still an issue. Just wondering if a better solution was found?

Comment: yep, still happening for me. I don't really play music on my computer anymore so haven't noticed. Looks like reflex in the answer is still downloadable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was driving me crazy, so I wrote a little menu bar app to make the media keys only affect iTunes:

http://stuntsoftware.com/reflex/

Comment: This works right away moving to applications directory and opening the app. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work for Spotify too? Yes, yes it does. Be careful he is a hero.

Comment: It is a little buggy though. Doesn't always work.